# Where to ask questions related to consciousness

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I see there is a cognitive science, a philosophy a psychology, a Buddhist Stack Exchange. But non of these really value answers, nor questions related to consciousness in the broad sense. They often say the answer of question is invalid because it is not scientific (mainstream science scientific that is). While it can be valuable questions or answers with respect to the purpose of life. There is nothing more important to me then topics related to developing more consciousness and purpose of life related. Where can I go with these Q&As?

Comment: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Won't They seem very picky. Not all is philosophy they say. It must have some literature background or so to be a philosophical question.

Comment: Why not post in [Buddhism](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/) site? There are over 490+ posts [on consciousness](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=consciousness)

Comment: @MikedeKlerk If you're interested in Consciousness/Perceptronium from the paranormal aspect (the omnipresent substance that feels subjectively self-aware), there is: [Paranormal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84880/paranormal) proposal (see [What exactly counts as paranormal?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/20019/61861)).

Comment: @HackerKarma On Buddhism site, the consciousness is limited on Buddhism tradition, the same as on Mi Yodeya it's limited to Kaballah. All other questions outside of their tradition would be closed down, as I've tried already and other SE sites are limited only into mainstream science which doesn't recognise it as kind of omnipresent energy, as there are no reproducible ways to scientifically study this aspect.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for a place where people encourage each other in their efforts toward consciousness, helping each other to distill their views and stay on track, that is a very noble pursuit.

But Stack Exchange might not be your best bet.

Folks here mostly build communities around topics which have empirically right or wrong answers. They either adhere to traditional science, or have well defined community guidelines which allow members to build consensus around open-ended topics. Since consciousness is a (valuable but) very amorphous topic, the SE sites where you can ask related questions tend to require that posts be presented in the context of science (i.e. CogSci SE) or a known discipline (i.e. Buddhism).

Answer (score 10):

http://cogsci.stackexchange.com:

> Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for practitioners, researchers, and students in cognitive science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry.

Has a tag [consciousness](/questions/tagged/consciousness):

> For questions that have to do with a sense of being awake and aware in the literal sense, but also those having to do with the nature of the mind and the formation of the individual.

Two of the most famous psychologists worked with consciousness and the unconcious mind.

- Carl Gustav Jung was the founder of a neopsychoanalytic school of psychology, which he named Analytical Psychology. He created the concept of the Collective Unconscious.
- Sigmund Freud was the founder of the Psychoanalytic school of psychology, a movement that popularized the theory that unconscious motives control much behaviour. Freud is best known for his theories of the Unconscious Mind. He created a Structural Model of the Psyche - Conscious/ Unconscious Mind, Ego/ Id/ Superego.

Answer (score 3):

The term consciousness is ambiguous and it depends what kind of answers you're looking for:

- consciousness related to Buddhist philosophy, try at: [Buddhism SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consciousness),
- consciousness related to Jewish mysticism, try at: [Mi Yodeya SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=consciousness)
- consciousness as philosophy of mind, try at: [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consciousness)
- consciousness in terms of being aware in the literal sense, try at: [Cognitive Sciences SE](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consciousness)

Comment: I think this example question: `If you measure only reported cases, where on Earth are you in the most risk of being abducted by Aliens?` is a pity. But I think this question: `Is telepathy limited by the speed of light?` is seriously a good one. THere lots of questions to make fun of subjects. Yet this question seems again a good and serious one: `What's the difference between astral projection and lucid dream?`. He its yours! I guess I will join :)